# XQuery and distinct-values

Tags: xml, xquery, distinct-values

I have this XML:

```
<university>
<departaments>
    <departament sl="AA">
        <subject>Numbers</subject>
        <categories>
            <categorie>
                <name type="one">Mathematics</name>
            </categorie>
            <categorie>
                <name type="one">Physics</name>
            </categorie>
            <categorie>
                <name type="two">Other</name>
            </categorie>
        </categories>
    </departament>
    <departament sl="BB">
        <subject>Letters</subject>
        <categories>
            <categorie>
                <name type="one">Philosophy</name>
            </categorie>
            <categorie>
                <name type="two">Language</name>
            </categorie>
            <categorie>
                <name type="two">Other</name>
            </categorie>
        </categories>
    </departament>
</departaments>
</university>
```

And I need to obtain the names with his attributes, ordered by length and without duplicates names. I.e.this xml:

```
<name type="two">Other</name>
<name type="one">Physics</name>
<name type="two">Language</name>
<name type="one">Philosophy</name>
<name type="one">Mathematics</name>
```

I have this code, but don't work.

```
for $name in distinct-values(doc ("uni.xml")//categorie/name)
order by string-length($name)
return $name
```

Somebody could help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
for $name in distinct-values(doc("uni.xml")//categorie/name)
order by string-length($name)
return (doc("uni.xml")//categorie/name[.=$name])[1]
```

Comment: The StackOverflow protocol is not to respond in a comment, but simply to mark the answer as accepted by clicking on the tick/check mark in the margin. This is useful for people who come along later with a similar question, so they know that the answer works. (It also gives the answerer reputation points, which some SO members seem to care about rather a lot).